# Focus on next input with React Form Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form, tsx

I created a custom `TextInput` with `React Hook Form`, I'm trying to set the focus into the next `TextInput`.

I explain better: in order to focus the next element, I can easily create an `useRef` like this:

```
const passwordRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
<FormProvider {...methods}>
  <TextInput
    name="email"
    label="Email"
    keyboardType="email-address"
    autoCompleteType="email"
    rules={{
      required: true,
      pattern: emailPattern,
    }}
    returnKeyType="next"
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    errorLabel={{
      type: "pattern",
      label: "Your email isn't correct",
    }}
    onSubmitEditing={() => passwordRef.current?.focus()}
  />
  <TextInput
    name="password"
    label="Password"
    autoCompleteType="password"
    returnKeyType="go"
    rules={{ required: true }}
    secureTextEntry={true}
    inputRef={passwordRef}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    onSubmitEditing={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
  />
</FormProvider>;
```

In this way, I can easily set the focus, but I'm trying to make it generic: the `TextInput` knows who is the next element to focus.

Hope my problem is clear, any suggestion is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextComponentWrapper` can be like **(UPDATED)**

```
const TextInputWrapper = (props) => {
  const [isFocused, setFocus] = useState(false);

  const { currentIndex, inputsLength, forwardRef, onSubmit, nextFocusRef } =
    props;

  // create dynamic refs for inputs
  const inputsRef = React.useRef([...Array(inputsLength)].map(() => React.createRef()));

  const onSubmitEditing = () => {
    inputsRef?.current[currentIndex + 1]?.current?.focus();
  };

  const onBlur = () => {
    setFocus(false);
  };

  const onFocus = () => {
    setFocus(true);
  };

  return (
    <Input
      onBlur={onBlur}
      ref={inputsRef.current[currentIndex]}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      returnKeyType={onSubmit ? "done" : "next"}
      onSubmitEditing={onSubmit || onSubmitEditing}
      blurOnSubmit={false}
    />
  );
};
export default TextInputWrapper;
```

Create `CustomHooks` like

```
import {useRef} from 'react';

export const useInputProps = (formObj, name) => {
  const {control, errors} = formObj;
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  return {forwardRef: inputRef, control: control, name, error: errors[name]};
};
```

Usage like

```
import { useInputProps } from "./CustomHooks";

const emailProps = useInputProps(formObj, "email");
const passwordProps = useInputProps(formObj, "password");

<View>
  <TextInput inputsLength={2} currentIndex={0} {...emailProps} />

  <TextInput
    inputsLength={2}
    currentIndex={1}
    onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    {...passwordProps}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: In this way, the component that uses TextInput has to create N `refInput` as `TextInput`, and as you can see from my post I'm already doing this. I'm trying to automate it inside `TextInput` (it's a custom component)

Comment: @Shifenis you want to focus on the next element without providing the current element any ref to the next element? how you are planning to call .focus()  then?

Comment: @Shifenis please check my updated answer, I have created textInput wrapper and usage exmaple

Comment: @shubhamjha my idea was to create a component that creates N references for each TextInput, without any logic inside the component that uses the form

Comment: @Shifenis Check my update answer

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani your answer is quite similar to my idea, but you have to create manually `ref_input` to pass to `TextInput`, I will probably find a logic to move them inside a wrapper in order to create the refs for each input

Comment: @Shifenis I have updated my answer please check. It's just an idea

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Wrapper` component to enclose the `TextInput`s, then use `Children.map` to loop through each of them dynamically and add the `onSubmitEditing` function while assigning refs.

```
function Wrapper({ children, onLastOnSubmitEditing }) {
  const arrayChildren = Children.toArray(children);
  const childrenRef = useRef([]);
  return <>{Children.map(arrayChildren, (child, index) => {
        const onSubmitEditing = () => {
           if (index < arrayChildren.length - 1) {
               childrenRef.current[index+1].focus();
           } else {
             onLastOnSubmitEditing();
           }
        }
        return cloneElement(child, { ref: (ref) => (childrenRef.current[index] = ref), onSubmitEditing });
     })}</>
}
```

Usage:

```
<FormProvider {...methods}>
  <Wrapper onLastOnSubmitEnding={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <TextInput
      name="email"
      label="Email"
      keyboardType="email-address"
      autoCompleteType="email"
      rules={{
        required: true,
        pattern: emailPattern,
      }}
      returnKeyType="next"
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      errorLabel={{
        type: "pattern",
        label: "Your email isn't correct",
      }}
    />
    <TextInput
      name="password"
      label="Password"
      autoCompleteType="password"
      returnKeyType="go"
      rules={{ required: true }}
      secureTextEntry={true}
      inputRef={passwordRef}
      blurOnSubmit={false}
    />
  </Wrapper>
</FormProvider>;
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-euclid-rqtrrb

Comment: Your solution doesn't work fine, it generates an error in run time, i will try to resolve, and in that case I will update this post with the solution

Comment: Sorry about that, there is a typo and I have updated the code. I also included a codesandbox link to demonstrate the solution @Shifenis. (the csb example does not have `onSubmitEditing` so I replaced it with a `onKeyPress`